# I'm a Vietnamese citizen traveling to Taiwan with a valid US visa. Can I enter Taiwan visa-free if the US visa will expire during my stay?

Tags: visas, taiwan, vietnamese-citizens

I'm from Vietnam and have a multiple entry to Taiwan. My USA visa expires on Sept 11 and my flight to Taiwan is on the 5th. Would it be a problem for me?

Edit: Vietnamese citizens who have valid visa from USA can enter Taiwan without a Taiwanese visa. I'm planning to do that. However, my USA visa will expire 5 days after my arrival date. So i'm just being a little careful and check.

Comment: I think there is no problem if you visit Taiwan for a few days and leave before the visa expires. Before you travel, please make sure you meet the requirements as follows:                                                                  1) must apply for an “Authorization Certificate’ online

2) check-in with the approved download Certificate

3) passport valid for more than six months

4) onward and return ticket

5) no criminal record

Comment: @pnuts I don't have a valid visa for Taiwan. I'm planning to go there with my USA visa. That's why I asked the question...

Comment: @pnuts I don't have a multiple entry to Taiwan...

Comment: @pnuts but he's saying he *doesn't* have a ME...unless I'm misreading?

Comment: @pnuts ah in the question. His latest comment seems to contradict that.  Ah, I see you're saying that too.  Sigh.  forever4, you really need to update the question, not put stuff in comments.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [National Immigration Agency of Taiwan](http://www.boca.gov.tw/ct.asp?xItem=6464&ctNode=868&mp=2):

> (Applicable to citizens of India, Indonesia, **Vietnam**, the Philippines
>   and Thailand)
>
> Citizens of the five listed Asian countries should initiate an
>   eligibility check before filing an online application for Travel
>   Authorization Certificate:
>
> Basic requirements (All conditions must be met):
>
> - The applicant's passport is valid for at least six months. (This  means that the passport is valid for at least six months when its 
>     holder arrives in Taiwan and not when the application is filed 
>     online.)
> - The applicant should possess a return plane or ferry ticket.
> - The applicant is never employed as a blue-collar worker in Taiwan.
>
> Additional Requirements: (Possessed one of the following documents).
>
> - The applicant should possess a valid (1) Permanent Resident Card or
> - (2) Entry Visa
>
> Of any one of the following countries: **the United States**, Canada, the
>   United Kingdom, Japan, Australia, and New Zealand;
>   or one of the signatories of the Schengen Agreement. (including an
>   electric one).
>
> A single-entry visa becomes invalid once it has already been used.
>   However, a used single-entry visa might be acceptable for the purpose
>   of immigration inspection to enter Taiwan, if it meets the following
>   conditions:
>
> - On the same continuing journey, the visa holder uses it to enter the visa issuing country prior to his/her arrival in Taiwan; and
> - **The visa holder will arrive in Taiwan before its expiration date.**
>
> The applicant must present the required documents for inspection when
>   entering Taiwan; entry will be denied if the required documents are
>   not produced.

Therefore the answer is **yes**, you can enter Taiwan at any time while your US visa is still valid, even if it will expire during your stay. Don't forget to file the [online application](https://niaspeedy.immigration.gov.tw/nia_southeast/) for a Travel Authorization Certificate before you arrive.